# Is there a way to grab data from this txt file in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am using Beyond Compare and I have gotten it to ouput if there are any differences into a txt file. However, I want to script this in powershell so that if there are no differences in files, the script will continue and do something else. However, I am not sure this is possible. I have looked through Select-String, but unsure if that will be able to do what I am looking for. Attached is what the txt file looks like when there are no differences as well as what it looks like when there are differences.

[image: Differences]
[image: No Differences]

Is it possible to convert name, size, or modified in the txt file into a variable and then do a condition on whether it is null? Or is there is another way I can do what I am trying to achieve in Powershell? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the content of the file as (formatted) text rather then a picture, see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need to know is *whether* any differences were found, the following should do:

```
$noDiffs = '' -eq ((Get-Content -Raw report.txt) -split '\r?\n-+\r?\n')[1].Trim()
```

- `(Get-Content -Raw report.txt) -split '\r?\n-+\r?\n` splits the entire input file by the the divider line (`----...`) following the table-header line, using a [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) (regular expression).
- `[1]` looks a the 2nd element of the resulting array, i.e., whatever comes after the divider line, trims any leading and trailing whitespace, and the result is tested for being the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

With all respect to the question and the answer from @mklement0.
Using [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) in a PowerShell script is putting the [cart before the horse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cart_before_the_horse).
There are a lot of [cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/cmdlet-overview?view=powershell-7)s in PowerShell which would let you easily compare folders (and a lot more) without doing any text scraping.
As using [Compare-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-7) togehter with [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7) for the given example:

```
Compare-Object (Get-ChildItem .\Test) (Get-ChildItem .\Test1) -Property Name, Length, LastWriteTime
```

If you want to do a recursive compare on the **relative path**, you can do:

```
Compare-Object (Get-ChildItem .\Test -Recurse -Name) (Get-ChildItem .\Test1 -Recurse -Name)
```

Note that the `-Name` parameter will only list relative path **strings**, if you also want to compare `Length` and `LastWriteTime`, You can do:

```
$TestFolder = 'C:\Test'
$Test1Folder = 'C:\Test1'

$TestFiles  = Get-ChildItem $TestFolder  -File -Recurse |
    Select-Object *,@{N='RelativePath'; E={$_.FullName.SubString($TestFolder.Length)}}
$Test1Files = Get-ChildItem $Test1Folder -File -Recurse |
    Select-Object *,@{N='RelativePath'; E={$_.FullName.SubString($Test1Folder.Length)}}

Compare-Object $TestFiles $Test1Files -Property RelativePath,Length,LastWriteTime
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried this and love using this for smaller folders. However, I am comparing folders that have upwards of 1-5TB in them of countless folders and files to iterate through.. I ran compare-object -recurse on a little smaller folder that had 450GB, but it was still churning away 2 hours later. I am not sure if that is to be expected or if I did something wrong. However, I ran the same folder in Beyond Compare and it took less than 10-15 minutes to do the same thing. That is why I have reverted to Beyond Compare for this project. Thanks.

Comment: I guess, you comparing *every* file in *every* folder with *every* file in the other folder. In case you want to **compare the relate path**, you also need to add the `-Name` parameter. See the example I have added to the answer.